# Vi scrolling in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, vim, vi

Is there a way to rebind j and k to scroll pages in Firefox or Chrome, or addons available just for vi-like scrolling that **aren't** entire emulators like vimperator and vimium? All I want to do is scroll from the home row, without the clutter from those plugins which I don't need.

Comment: 1. `j` and `k` are not for scrolling. 2. You can search the available addons directly from Firefox and Chrome themselves.

Comment: I want to use j and k for scrolling pages like in vimperator but without the other vi functionality which gets in the way, which is why a rebind is ideal. I clearly wouldn't be asking this question if I had already tried searching for both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome Vimium which provides a lot of shortcuts

- h/j/k/l:      scroll left/down/up/right
- (number+)d(u):    half page down(up)

Check [here for more Chrome Vimium Tips, Tricks](https://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2019/04/awesome-tips-about-chrome-vimium.html)